# Formula for pricing paintings

Tags: linear-algebra, area

When pricing paintings artists often multiply a factor (*F*) by *linear size* (height + width) opposed to *area* (height x width) thus avoiding an extreme disparity in price between small and large paintings. (The multiplying factor will determine the monetary amount for all the paintings)

***A painting of 10" + 16" multiplied by a factor of '40' = $1040***

Simplified example below:

**20"+40" = 60** and **40"+60" = 100** - giving a reasonable 40% price difference between prices.

**20"x40" = 800** and **40"x60" = 2400** - a staggering 300% difference in price.

However using this linear size pricing method gives rise to another problem:

Lets say we had two paintings, one **20"x40"** and the other **30"x30"**.

**20+40 = 30+30** so in this case both paintings would be calculated at the same price (60 x *F*), despite the fact that one painting is actually 10 square inches larger in area.

So when using the *linear size* instead of *area* for price calculations clearly the result would also need to be multiplied by a greater amount the squarer a painting is.

I'm wondering if some sort of calculation involving square root would be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer (at the OP's request), any price function of the form $a(h+w)+b\sqrt{hw}$ with positive coefficients $a$ and $b$ will scale linearly while giving a higher price to a painting of greater area compared to one of lesser area but identical linear size.

Comment: I found that with dimensions in cm the sweet spot for me was (a = 0.02] and [b = 48] giving a value in $CAD, thanks again - a perfect elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a good solution using trigonometry.

I regarded the height and width dimensions as if they were right triangle sides.
Using these known sides I could calculate the Hypotenuse, which increases inversely to area.

**Price = (*Height* + *Width* − Hypotenuse) × *Factor***

p = h + w - √(h² + w²) * f

This still produces a linear price scale, whilst also giving a *higher* value to a painting with greater area compared to one of a lesser area but *identical linear size*.

Comment: I've found a few instances where this doesn;t work out, back to the drawing board...

Comment: Any price function of the form $a(h+w)+b\sqrt{hw}$ with positive coefficients $a$ and $b$ will scale linearly while giving a higher price to a painting of greater area compared to one of lesser area but identical linear size.

Comment: How about this example: 5x5 has an area of 25, 3x8 has a smaller area of 24. However my calculations give the 3x8 a higher price, is that wrong?

Comment: I had written your calculation wrong, I understand now why you need a and b, to control the scale right? This is perfect, thank you! Please add this solution as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Done. If you find what you consider a "sweet spot" for the ratio of the coefficients $a$ and $b$, I'd be interested. You can ping me with a comment to my answer.